# Flutter convert JSON string to multi-level list

Tags: json, flutter

I want to convert a string to multi-level list, but I cannot find a efficient way to do.

From String:
[[1,2,3],[1,2]]

To List:
List< List < int>>

Comment: You can checkout [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) to parse your JSON string. It will generate the model for the required language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a funtion

```
List<List<int>> convert(String val){
    List<List<int>> list = [];
  jsonDecode(val).forEach((mainList) {
    List<int> subList = [];
    mainList.forEach((sList) {
      subList.add(sList);
    });
    list.add(subList);
  });
  return list;
}
```

Also import `dart:convert;`

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = '[[1,2,3],[1,2]]';
  List<List<int>> list=[];
  for(String s in str.split('],[')){
    List<int> l = [];
    String formattedString = s.replaceAll('[','').replaceAll(']','');
    for(String innerS in formattedString.split(',')){
        l.add(int.parse(innerS));
      print(l);
    }
    list.add(l);
  }
```

Output: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var jsonMap = "[[1,2,3],[1,2]]";
  List<List<int>> items = (jsonDecode(jsonMap) as List).map((lst) => 
      (lst as List).map((i) => (i as int)).toList()).toList();
  print(items);
}
```